# Import Notebook in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: documentation, workbench

Wolfram Workbench 3* Eclipse (2018-09), Windows 10, MMA 11.0.1.0 [New Eclipse & Workbench installations & this is the 1st test]

(* I can no longer find a version ref, all I know for certain is Wolfram Workbench Core & webMathematica versions are 10.1.822; installed per instructions on support site [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221))

Wolfram Workbench implies it can import existing notebooks to a project; reality begs to differ.

Problems so far:

1. The import (File...Import...Wolfram... Code from a File) wizard presents an unexplained option of no obvious effect - "Keep Linear Syntax". This is referenced in Wolfram documentation as an index heading ["Lin"](https://reference.wolfram.com/alphaindex/Lin.html) but in the section referenced (Input Syntax) there is no mention of it.
2. If I choose to import to .m file (importing only initialisation cells) only 10 lines of code appear for the 50+ initialisation cells that actually exist. Line breaks seem to have become "?" (even though the convert line delimiters remains Windows (default) as do right arrows ("->") in option specifications. **The result is therefore both incomplete and syntactically incorrect** (and useless)

One example of a mangled initialisation cell...

> sqlServerDeveloper = {"SQLDEVELOPER", 11235,"SQLDEVELOPER"}; (*
>   Server, Port, Instance Name*)?sqlServerExpress ={"SQLEXPRESS",
>   55514,"SQLEXPRESS"};?activeSQLServer =
>   sqlServerDeveloper;?sqlServerNameIdx = 1;?sqlServerPortIdx =
>   2;?sqlServerInstanceIdx
>   =Length[activeSQLServer];?activeSQLServerIP[server_List] := "localhost:" <> ToString[server[[3](https://www.semanticscholar.org/topic/Linear-syntax/1374671)]];?activeSQLServerString[
>   server_List] := "\\LOTAN\\" <>
>   server[[2](https://reference.wolfram.com/alphaindex/Lin.html)];?activeSQLServerInstance[server_List] :=
>   server[[sqlServerInstanceIdx]];

**Questions**

1. How can one import existing notebooks correctly and completely into a workbench project as anything other than a notebook... or is that NOT what import is for at all?
2. What is this "Linear Syntax", and should I keep it on import or not?

Update 28/10/2018:

> Linear syntax is a computer-programming term for an expression that can be parsed from left to right. Linear syntax implies the ability to write code without the use of line-feed or carriage-return characters. Although the use of such characters is recommended for code readability, they are optional, as compilers do not rely on them to parse and compile the code. See [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/topic/Linear-syntax/1374671)

Imports performed with "Keep Linear Syntax" checked & unchecked produced identical text. Purpose/intended effect still unknown, and, since MMA syntax *is* linear syntax, I don't know how it could not be kept.

*Comment*

The observed behaviour is clearly unacceptable, so the setup must be misbehaving as a result of config issues beyond Wolfram's control, or PEBKAC, or...? Which? What? Why? Ideas?